# Are the shortcuts for YouTube and Vimeo set by the sites, or set by them being 'HTML5'

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts, vimeo

If  they're set by HTML5, does that mean the shortcuts are the same for both sites?

Or are shortcuts different and set per site, by the site?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether those shortcuts are exist or not. Note that Youtube and Vimeo use HTML5 (again see those HTML source code using your browser's developer tools if you don't sure).